Is there a way to use ExecuteExcel4Macro function with index function to retrieve values of a range (more than 1 cell) without looping?
I use ExecuteExcel4Macro function with index function since index can retrieve data from a closed workbook without the need of openning it. But, I want a dynamic function which retrieves the file path, the workbook name, sheet name and range info from a bunch of cells to get the values from the closed workbook.
I have the function to get values from a closed workbook which works well with a single cell. But to get values of a range I could only get the values by looping. Here is the part of the code:
If xlapp Is Nothing Then
    'Object must be created only once and not at each function call
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
End If

rng = "R1C1:R3C1"
f_path = "'" & file_name & "\[" & book_name & "]" & sheet_name & "'!" & rng

ReDim list_1(1 To rows_N, 1 To columns_N)
For i = 1 To rows_N
   For j = 1 To columns_N
      list_1(i, j) = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("INDEX(" & f_path & "," & i & "," & j & ")")
   Next j
Next i

The above code works fine while looping since it gets the values of one cell in each looping line.
Rather than this, I want to make the loop part like:
list_1 = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("INDEX(" & f_path & ", 0 , 0)")
to get all range without looping (due to being slow when a big range is selected). But this code always returns a single value that corresponds to the 2nd row and 2nd column item (if only 1 row/column then results as 2nd column/row item) which I don't know why. Is there a way to run this without any loop?

You can use ADO and SQL to query and get the required data from a closed workbook. Without more details, I cannot help more. Try searching with the keywords ADO closed workbook

Would help to show the entire function, and exactly how you're calling it.

Pretty sure your ExecuteExcel4Macro approach can only retrieve one cell at a time.

As @TimWilliams said, there is no way to 'peek' into a closed workbook for more than 1 cell with the ExecuteExcel4Macro methods. If you're needing to peek into workbooks without opening them in Excel, then consider the various 'ClosedXML' libraries that read & parse the Excel files XML content

@TimWilliams Thanks for the reply, I read similar comments on related function comments that ExecuteExcel4Macro can retrieve one cell, so I guess you are right. Thus, I just defined another UDF using ADODB connection and recordset asignments.
